# OpenMP task in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I am fairly new with `Java Threads`, I normally use C with it comes to parallelization. To parallelize algorithm that has the same pattern as the one it follows:

```
void traverse(node* p)
{
    if (p->left)
        #pragma omp task // p is firstprivate by default
        traverse(p->left);
    if (p->right)
        #pragma omp task // p is firstprivate by default
        traverse(p->right);
}
```

I would use the task directive of `openMP`, for example.

**Task Description**

> When a thread encounters a task construct, a task is generated from
>   the code for the associated structured block.  The encountering thread
>   may immediately execute the task, or defer its execution. In the
>   latter case, any thread in the team may be assigned the task.
>   Completion of the task can be guaranteed using task synchronization
>   constructs. A task construct may be nested inside an outer task, but
>   the task region of the inner task is not a part of the task region of
>   the outer task.

My question is:

How I could implement this same idea (task) with `Java Threads`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pragmas of OpenMP do make parallelization a little easier.

In Java, you would first need to create a class that implements Runnable.
  - example: public Class Traverse implements Runnable

You then just neew to create the class and call 'run' to start the thread.

```
private void traverse(node p) 
{
   Traverse t = null;

    if (p.left)
       t = new Traverse(p.left);
    if (p->right)
       t = new Traverse(p.right)

    t.run();   // start thread. this call will not wait for run to finishes
}
```